# how to pass a variable through a url

Tags: php, variables

I created a field in WP customizer and I'm trying to pull whatever value I enter from another file. Beforehand, this worked:

```
private $endpoint = "http://www.website.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?ws-id=12345";
```

and now I am trying to do something like this (I'm new at this):

```
$website_api_key = echo get_theme_mod('website-api-key');

private $endpoint = "http://www.website.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?ws-id=" . $website_api_key;
```

How do I get this to work correctly?

Comment: In what way is the result different from the version that worked?  How specifically is this not working?

Comment: Considering you have a visibility keyword there (private), it seems to be that $endpoint is a property, not a variable.   The property's default value cannot be an expression.  Set the value in the constructor if need be, also you'd have to figure out where $website_api_key lives.

Comment: @David I'm getting a white screen on the front end doing it the way I'm trying now...

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the variable in the url correctly. Now you just have to grab it. When you visit a webpage, you are using a GET request, so these "url variables" can be grabbed through the $_GET array.

All you have to do to accomplish this is do something like this:

```
$myvar = $_GET['ws-id'];
```

[Here](https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php) is a good article to give you more information on this

Comment: so I write it like this? :

$website_api_key = echo get_theme_mod('website-api-key');

$myvar = $_GET['website_api_key'];

private $endpoint = "http://www.website.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?ws-id=" . $myvar;

Comment: @user3547342 Yes I believe that will work as long as `get_theme_mod()` returns the correct information.